# Accessing a Salesforce sandbox through API

Tags: api, sandbox, php, wsdl

can someone with salesforce API integration help me understand the requirements to access a client's Sandbox? I need to access the sandbox and pull data into our MySQL server.

I hired a programmer but he seems to be having a hard time accessing the sandbox and I want to try to help by guiding him in the right direction? Client provided us with the following credentials for the sandbox.

Target URL: http://xxx.my.salesforce.com 
Username: user@clientdomain.com.beta 
password: xxxxxxx 
token: gave us a token to access through API.

Your help will be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Are you sure you're using the *sandbox* login? That's usually the culprit here. It should be `https://test.salesforce.com/`.

Comment: @sfdcfox are you a bot :?

Comment: I guess that's a compliment? No, I'm sfdcfox. You know, the same guy over here: http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/18918

Comment: That would mean... the same guy that's been threatening to write a blog for 9 months, and haven't got to it yet, lol.

Comment: lol. I just realized. You're fast at answering questions. But I'm faster (sometimes). Thanks, I'll take that to mean I'm doing my unofficial job in life, to help people along ;-)

Comment: Oh, and that blog is almost ready. No, seriously.

Answer (score 11):

In addition to sfdcfox pointing out that you generally login to a sandbox at https://test.salesforce.com, there is another option. Since you are using my domain you can login through its URL:

Production URL: `https://mydomain.my.salesforce.com`

Sandbox URL: `https://mydomain--sandboxName.[Instance].my.salesforce.com`. Note that the instance can change when the sandbox is refreshed.

Does the client have it configured so you must login through their custom domain? If not, use https://test.salesforce.com.

Comment: Thanks so much for this, it helped me a lot.  I would have thought the WSDL generated from a site would have handled the case where a custom domain is needed but then I'm a bone head.  And for bone heads like me I'll point out that you'll need to edit the WSDL's service address for the custom domain.

Answer (score 2):

> For access via the API or a client, the user must add their security
>   token to the end of their password in order to log in. A security
>   token is an automatically-generated key from Salesforce. For example,
>   if a user’s password is mypassword, and their security token is
>   XXXXXXXXXX, then the user must enter mypasswordXXXXXXXXXX to log in.

Source:
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_concepts_security.htm

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I was able to log in to sandbox (C# app)

config

```
  <endpoint address="https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/32.0/<org id goes here>"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SoapBinding1"
      contract="sforce.Soap" name="SoapTest" />
```

Make sure that username is appended with ".[sanboxname]".

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=data_sandbox_create.htm&language=en_US

Users can log in to the sandbox at https://test.salesforce.com by appending .sandbox_name to their Salesforce usernames. For example, if a username for a production organization is user1@acme.com, and the sandbox is named “test”, the modified username to log in to the sandbox is user1@acme.com.test.

The password needs to have security token appended. If password = test and token = 123, then you need test123

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is hitting this issue, also be sure to check that you have taken the url from Classic and not Lightning. Below is the difference

https://test--dev.cs52.my.salesforce.com/services/

https://test--dev.lightning.force.com/services/